# GridView ASP.NET c# dados da mesma tabela

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tenho a seguinte tabela no SQL com os seguintes campos (id, nome, dia semana,ativo).
id a chave primária do tipo inteiro;
nome nvchar
dia semana nvchar;
ativo bit;
e tenho os seguintes dados na tabela
1 ;jose ;segunda feira;1;
2; jose; quartafeira; 1;
eu quero que mostrar estes dados em uma gridview do tipo;

```
Tipo colunas: TEXTBOX || Checkbox || Checkbox|| Checkbox||...
Nome colunas:  nome || segunda || terça || quarta ||...
Dados:        jose  || x       ||        || x ||...
```

ao editar remove o registo daquele dia, e caso nao exista cria um novo registo para o respetivo dia.
Estou a fazer isto em web forms aplication.
Espero que dé para entender o que pretendo.

Comment: Tenta pular linha, tente ser mais específico, releia sua pergunta com calma e tente fazê-la de maneira que facilite o entendimento e que seja mais completa possível (detalhada)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Template.aspx.cs" Inherits="Template" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Explorando o GridView - Visual C#</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <table width="60%" align="center" bgcolor="#cccccc" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <br />
                                <font face="arial" size="2">
                                    <b>Explorando o GridView - Visual C#</b><br />
                                    Por Felipe Albuquerque<br />
                                    <a href="mailto:f.albuquerquedealmeida@gmail.com">f.albuquerquedealmeida@gmail.com</a><br />
                                    <a href="felipealbuquerq.blogspot.com" target="_blank">http://http://felipealbuquerq.blogspot.com</a>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td><br /><hr size="1" noshade /><br /></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <font face="arial" size="2">
                                    <table width="100%" align="center">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Utilizando Template Columns</b></td>
                                            <td align="right"><a href="Default.aspx"><< Indice</a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>"
                                                    SelectCommand="SELECT [*] FROM [Agenda]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" SortExpression="Nome" />
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SegundaFeira" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="TercaFeira" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="QuartaFeira" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="QuintaFeira" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SextaFeira" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td><hr size="1" noshade /></td></tr>
                        <tr><td align="right"><a href="http://beta.asp.net"><img border="0" src="Images/ASPNET.gif" /></a>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se é possível? É Claro que sim.
Mas se você realmente quer ter ajuda com o seu caso, você precisa fornecer detalhes mais específicos como sugeriu o @tchicotti.

Com o que é possível entender com a sua pergunta, só é possível dizer que sim, e que na exibição você precisa preencher os "checkboxes" de acordo com os dados retornados pela sua consulta, e, de acordo com a ação do usuário você precisará ou atualizar um registro ou inserir um novo registro.